# Which server software can be used to robot remote control from a browser?

Tags: remote, webrtc

I'm considering to make a Raspberry car robot with camera which can be controlled from a web browser (via WebRTC). Is there any services/SaaS/open-source-software which I can use for building networking (video and commands transfer)?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it with WebRTC? Would you be open to doing it another way, but still through a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try or use UV4L for this. It supports WebRTC and the server can run custom webapps. The UV4L software can be found at https://www.linux-projects.org . There are also examples and other tools useful for robot-specific applications. Unfortunately, it is not opensource, but it is free to use.